# just trying to get the right inductor

Tags: identification, inductor

[image]

I have a shielded inductor off a JL audio amp. It is marked **•A1**.

Does anyone know what it is and what its specs are? I need a replacement for it.

Comment: Show a picture, please.

Comment: Just added a photo.

Comment: Dimensions? Do you have access to an LCR meter? Why do you need to replace it?

Comment: thats the good one on the amp, the other 3 burnt to a crisp.. I need replacements. i have a fluke 87v which won't read it and i have a cheap little honeytek A6013L which should read it. just not too sure of the setting to use.

Comment: remove it from the circuit and measure it on the inductance setting. Get DCR too if you can.

Comment: Far too little information. Useful would be photos in detail and whole PCB, model, what you have tried. Possible electrical size and use if known. ...

Comment: I have an LCR Meter coming today.. let you know what I find after Amazon comes. Thanks for all the help so far, much appreciated.

Comment: On the LCR meter under 200uh I get a reading of 12.4 Idk if its good or bad. The other uh settings don't read anything.